# ERROR openFile writing on ExternalStorage when Status is MOUNTED. Manifest permission OK

Tags: android, ioexception

and first of all... THANK YOU!
I'm trying to make work the code related at http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html
but there's something wrong when creating a file:

```
  private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    Log.i(TAG, "Entered ....createImageFile....StorageState= " + Environment.getExternalStorageState());
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";

    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = null;
    try{

        image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
        );
    } catch (IOException ex){
        Log.i(TAG, "Entered ....createImageFile....File= NOT CREATED");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.i(TAG, "Entered ....createImageFile....File= " + image.toString());

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

Error:

```
Error stack:(See state of Environment.getExternalStorageState()  is mounted )

> 
11-22 06:36:20.322: I/Photo(1172): Entered ....dispatchTakePictureIntent....
11-22 06:36:35.183: I/Photo(1172): Entered ....createImageFile....StorageState= **mounted**
11-22 06:36:45.072: I/Photo(1172): Entered ....createImageFile....File= NOT CREATED
11-22 06:36:54.985: W/System.err(1172): java.io.IOException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
11-22 06:36:55.044: W/System.err(1172):     at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:948)
11-22 06:36:55.073: W/System.err(1172):     at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:1013)
11-22 06:36:55.093: W/System.err(1172):     at com.example.prueba2.MainActivity.createImageFile(MainActivity.java:102)
```

My Android Manifest declares: ( I tried both)

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

or

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
                 android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
```

And my AVD is created with SDCard = 50MB and target API = 18

**UPDATED to answer greenapps comments**  Sorry. I've badly explined!! ....Not Solved yetI've added `File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        if ( !storageDir.exists()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "storageDir does not exist: " + storageDir.getAbsolutePath());
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "storageDir exists: " + storageDir.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        if ( !storageDir.canWrite()){
            Log.i(TAG, "storageDir is not writable: " + storageDir.getAbsolutePath());
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "storageDir is writable: " + storageDir.getAbsolutePath());
            }`   and I get `11-22 07:55:35.112: I/Photo(1240): Entered ....createImageFile....StorageState= mounted
storageDir does not exist: /storage/sdcard/Pictures
storageDir is not writable: /storage/sdcard/Pictures
Entered ....createImageFile....File= NOT CREATED`

Comment: After definition of storageDir. Before you use `storageDir`. Add to your code `if ( !storageDir.exists()) { Log.i(TAG, "does not exist: " + storageDir.getAbsolutePath()); return null;} if ( !storageDir.canWrite())Log.i(TAG, "is not writable: " + storageDir.getAbsolutePath()); return null;}`. And check the return value after calling.

Comment: And check the return value for null after calling createImageFile(). Otherwise you get a null pointer exception if you try to use a File null object. You should also return a null in the catch block.

Comment: Now please tell what was the issue.

Comment: Please add all mentioned `return null` statements. It is silly to continue if the directory does not exist to begin with.

Comment: **partially SOLVED:** first AVD settings causes some issue... No problem in another distinct new  AVD. And again the same problem when back to first AVD. Thank you, **greenapps** !! for your attention. We recover the flow control with these *return null* , but logs does't resolve anything.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation. This is how I solved it.

Replace:

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
```

With:

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
```

make sure you call:

```
mkdirs() // and not mkdir()
```

Here's the code that should work for you:

```
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(), "whatever_directory_existing_or_not/sub_dir_if_needed/");
        storageDir.mkdirs(); // make sure you call mkdirs() and not mkdir()
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  // prefix
                ".jpg",         // suffix
                storageDir      // directory
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents

        mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
        Log.e("our file", image.toString());
        return image;
    }
```

I had a bad experience following the example given in [Android Studio Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html) and I found out that there are many others experiencing the same about this particular topic here in stackoverflow, that is because even if we set

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

the problem persists in some devices.

My experience was that the example worked when I tried it in debug mode, after that 3 more tests passed, it so happened that my SD was suddenly corrupted, but I don't think it had to do with their example (funny). I bought a new SD card and tried it again (because I could not reformat my sd, however I tried), only to realize that still both release and debug mode did the same error log: directory does not exist ENOENT. Finally, I had to create the directories myself whick will contain the captured pictures from my phone's camera. And I was right, it works just perfect.

I hope this helps you and others out there searching for answers.